# name mysql variables dynamically using row value

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I have a varchar column with words. I would like to dynamically create @variables and name each variable using the value from the column to keep count of each word.

```
//Define all variables in PHP dynamically
@word1:=0, @word2:=0;

//Select and count how many times each word exists
SELECT (@column_value:=@column_value+1) AS words FROM Data ORDER BY words
```

The "@column_value" above should be "@word1".."@word2" etc.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: why not just do this in PHP? Why the need for doing it in the query?

Comment: Too large of a database so I'm looking for a simple solution in sql.

Comment: Size of database shouldn't have anything to do with it. Your post is tagged PHP. If you aren't querying from PHP then the tag needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just count the words using normal counting SQL functionality like:

```
SELECT word, COUNT(word) as `count`
FROM Data
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY word ASC
```

Comment: Well this would work if I only wanted to count but i would like to get  lets say 10 rows of data associated with each word. Not looking for GROUP BY here.